How do I use Tesseract to read any Unicode character from an image?
I have the following implementation of Tesseract to identify any specified single English character:
 class Program
 {
     static void Main()
     {
         string imgPath = "./image.png";
         string tessDataPath = @"./tessdata";

         using var ocrEngine = new TesseractEngine(tessDataPath, "eng", EngineMode.Default);
         using var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(imgPath);

         using var page = ocrEngine.Process(img, PageSegMode.SingleChar);
         string text = page.GetText();
         Console.WriteLine("Recognized text: " + text);

         float confidence = page.GetMeanConfidence();
         Console.WriteLine("Confidence: " + confidence);
         Console.ReadLine();
     }
}

However, I want to be able to give it an image of a unicode character and it can identify it.
I've tried looking through https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata for a .traineddata file that would allow this (because I think that's how it works) but I couldn't find anything. As of now, my ./tessdata folder only contains the file eng.traineddata.
